# Laravel Echo Not Receiving Pusher Events (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, laravel-5, pusher, laravel-5.5, laravel-echo

I followed the guide at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#using-example-application

Laravel Echo seems to be subscribing fine:

[image: [img=http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/17/1104/h_1509839756_8674437_f177095891.png]]

I fire the event on the backend:

```
event(new TicketMessageSent($ticket, $reply));
```

They show up on pusher.com's Debug Console:

[image: pusher debug console showing the event]

But nothing happening in this callback:

```
Echo.channel(`tickets.${this.ticket.id}`)
    .listen('TicketMessageSent', (e) => {
        console.log('message broadcast received: ');
        console.log(e);
    });
```

I'm pulling my hear out over this. What could be wrong here?

## update 1

So I played around in chromes console, subscribing to a `chat` channel and listening/binding to a `msg` event:

[image: subscribing and listening]

And then in Pusher.com's Debug Console, I create an event:

[image: firing event in pushers debug console]

Lo' and behold, it worked!:

[image: received the event!]

Answer (score 0):

MY LORD. The event I was sending from Laravel Backend was on channel 'ticket' whereas the frontend was listening on 'tickets' (plural) hahahaha!